# How do I trigger a struts action from within javascript?

Tags: javascript, jakarta-ee, struts-1

I have searched the web for this but so far got nowhere.
I have the following javascript code:

```
function trigger(){
                var fdate = document.getElementById("d_date").value;
                var m = fdate.substring(fdate.indexOf('/')+1, fdate.lastIndexOf('/'));
                var y = fdate.slice(fdate.lastIndexOf('/')+1);

                form.action="/toEditDate.do?month="+m+"&year="+y+"&navigate";
                form.submit();

            }
```

an the following jsp element:

```
<html:text property="strCreationDate" size="10" maxlength="10" title="Date" 
styleId="d_date" onclick="displayCalendar(document.forms[0].strCreationDate,'dd/mm/yyyy',this)"
onchange="trigger();"/>
```

The code is adapted from what I've managed to dig up searching online. Only problem is when I change the text in the textbox nothing happens.

Comment: Changing the text in the textbox results in nothing happening

Comment: Anything in the javascript console?

Comment: the problem is that the calendar functionality you have might not trigger the onchange event

Comment: @Liviu aren't they separate events? One should affect the other right?

Comment: ok I may have assumed too much. Can you call the trigger function directly?

Comment: @Liviu I can trigger it. I tested by disabling the body and putting an alert in there so yes, it gets triggered

Comment: ok where do you get the form instance from?

Comment: from within the same JSP page. I'm on the freenode irc in bot the Javascript and strut channels

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4978/discussion-between-liviu-t-and-dark-star1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seems you need to pass in the form instance

```
function trigger(form){
            var fdate = document.getElementById("d_date").value;
            var m = fdate.substring(fdate.indexOf('/')+1, fdate.lastIndexOf('/'));
            var y = fdate.slice(fdate.lastIndexOf('/')+1);

            form.action="/toEditDate.do?month="+m+"&year="+y+"&navigate";
            form.submit();

        }
```

And the jsp change

```
<html:text property="strCreationDate" size="10" maxlength="10" title="Date" 
styleId="d_date" onclick="displayCalendar(document.forms[0].strCreationDate,'dd/mm/yyyy',this)"
onchange="trigger(document.getElementById('formId'));"/>
```

or if only one form on the page

```
<html:text property="strCreationDate" size="10" maxlength="10" title="Date" 
styleId="d_date" onclick="displayCalendar(document.forms[0].strCreationDate,'dd/mm/yyyy',this)"
onchange="trigger(document.forms[0]);"/>
```